# passing data to partial express js hbs

Tags: node.js, express, session, notifications

currently I am making a notification system with node/express/hbs and mysql. I can insert notification to the database properly , but I can't fetch it my partial file.

here is my code

```
  countNotification: async (req, res) => {
            await Notification.count({ where: { status: 'unread' } }).then((notification) => {
                if (notification) {
                    const dashNotification = req.notification;
                    return dashNotification;
                }
            });
        },



 app.use((req, res, next) => {
        res.locals.user = req.user;
        res.locals.notification = req.dashNotification;
        next();
    });
```

i have tried this like that but it is not working , anyone has any solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You should use your middleware above the router:**

```
     app.use((req, res, next) => {
            res.locals.user = req.user;
            res.locals.notification = req.dashNotification;
            next();
        });
      
    countNotification: async (req, res) => {
                await Notification.count({ where: { status: 'unread' } }).then((notification) => {
                    if (notification) {
                        const dashNotification = req.notification;
                        return dashNotification;
                    }
                });
            },
```